# When was a volume mounted?

Tags: linux, nfs

Is there any way to find the timestamp (without using logs) when a volume was mounted?

I'm having some issues with volumes being re-mounted but i would like to find out what since "when" a volume has been in mounted state .

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably ask this question at [*Super User*](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) instead. If you decide to do so, be sure to delete your question here so not to cross-post.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this can be seen from:

/proc/self/mountstats

There's a parameter called "age" who contains the time in seconds since the volume has been mounted.